# How to change Jasper report Print name

Tags: java, jasper-reports

When I send the jasper report to print, the printer shows the document name as "jasper report-report name" (When there is a printing que, document name is also "jasper report" ). How can I change it to another name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- ### Using JasperReports API

  If you are using [JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html) you should set report name with help of [JasperPrint.setName(java.lang.String name)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) method.

The sample:

```
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

    JasperPrint jrPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, getDataSource());
    if (reportName != null && reportName.length() > 0) {
        jrPrint.setName(reportName);
    }

    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);

    PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
    printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName("PDFCreator", null));

    JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();

    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jrPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printServiceAttributeSet);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);

    exporter.exportReport();
```

- ### Using iReport (editing report template)

  You can set report name in report template with help of ***`name`*** attribute:

  ```
  <jasperReport .. name="Sample report name to print" ..>
  ```

Comment: Thank you. I edited  the jasper repor name as you mentioned in the xml of iReport template. Then the report name was changed but still Document name remains as jasper report. That means, the printing dialog shows, document name=Jasper Report-My given name. now I want to remove that "Jasper report"document name.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this by accident, if you put a '/' before the name you want, it will remove the "JasperReports -" string from the print name.

```
JasperPrint jrPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, getDataSource());
if (reportName != null && reportName.length() > 0) {
        jrPrint.setName('/'+reportName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you and I'm glad that I think I found a way to work on the problem.

https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/master/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRPrintServiceExporter.java

Line 404:

```
printerJob.setJobName("JasperReports - " + jasperPrint.getName());
```

So apparently we just need to edit this line of code (remove the " "JasperReports - " + " part) and compile it and use our custom jar distribution package.

My only problem right now is that I have not tested it yet because I have never compiled a package from source. I will update my answer when I have figured out how to compile and tested it.

Answer (score 0):

printRequestAttributeSet will overwite setJobName without prefix ("JasperReports - ").
I am using japserreports-6.14

```
printRequestAttributeSet.add(
 new JobName("My software", null));
```